# how to update all documents from an array in mongoose and create them if they dont exists?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i have an array of ids of the documents i want to update, the problem is if they don't exists i want to be able to create them.

This is my schema:

```
const CarRanking= new Schema({ 
id:{
 type: String,
 lowercase: true,
 unique: true,
 required: true
},
count:{
    type:Number,
    default:1
},

},
{
 timestamps: true
});
```

My query looks like this:

```
let arrIds = ['car1','car2','car3'];
TestRanking.updateMany({
id : { "$in": arrIds}
},{  
                    //<<======= This failed to create if they dont exists  
                    //          because i don't know how to put 
                    //          the corresponding id from the arrIds
 $inc : {count: 1}
},{safe: true, upsert: true, new : true})
.exec()
.then((data)=>{
  res.json({data});
})
.catch(err=>{
  console.log(err);
  next(err)})
}
```

How can i acomplish the creation when they dont exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This upsert flag will only create one document in mongodb, for this to work you need to use [bulkwrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db-collection-bulkwrite) with [updateone](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-updateonemany).

Eg :

```
db.collection.bulkWrite( [
   { updateOne :
      {
         "filter" : {id : { "$in": arrIds}},
         "update" : <Your Doc>,
         "upsert" : true
      }
   }
] )
```

Comment: Thanks i though the documents were not getting created because i was not specifying the ids in the update